# Return forms values in the same page

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I use this code to return values and get them on a new page

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Thisisasecret!'

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('username')
    password = PasswordField('password')

@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #return '<h1>The username is {}. The password is {}.'.format(form.username.data, form.password.data)
        return redirect(url_for('form', username=form.username.data, password=form.password.data))
    return render_template('form.html', form=form,username=form.username.data,password=form.password.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Our form will be here!</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('form') }}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.username.label }}
    {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.password.label }}
    {{ form.password }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <p>name is: {{username}} </p>
    <p>password is: {{password}} </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I change this code to make it return the results below the submit button instead of opening a new web page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use jinja so that when you submit the form and redirect to the same page, you can pass the username and password as parameters to the view, you can add it below the submit button. Try using

```py
return redirect(url_for('form', username=username, password=password))
```

instead of

```py
return '<h1>The username is {}. The password is {}.'.format(form.username.data, form.password.data)
```

This will basically redirect to the same page and give you access to the username and password.

Comment: I did update the code above with your changes but still, nothing happens...
I get none statements, what did I miss?

Comment: I am not really sure how flask-wtf forms work, but I think the way of sending data to the HTML template is correct. Could you verify the value of `form.username.data` and `form.password.data` by printing it to the console before you redirect?